# Lennox air conditioner capacitor and compressor ohm readings

Tags: air-conditioning, compressor, capacitor, resistance

I have a Lennox 2.5 ton a/c unit, model 13ACD-036-230-05, with a blown dual run capacitor (the run terminal for the compressor is burnt off the can, the fan and common terminals are still intact, fan still running).

I had the cap replaced a couple years ago when the fan quit working.  I remember the 5/45 uf, 440 volt cap that was installed was close to the original cap that failed, but not exactly the same.

I ohm'd out the compressor and got 1.4 ohms S-C, 0.9 ohms R-C, 2.3 ohms S-R.  These values seem possibly reasonable to me, but according to [LennoxPros](https://m.lennoxpros.com/news/the-proper-way-to-ohm-a-single-phase-compressor), "The resistance between start(S) to common(C) is typically three-to-five times higher than run to common winding..." but they didn't state what resistance is actually expected.

What is the original cap rating (uf and voltage) for this a/c unit and what are the normal compressor resistance measurements?

[image: wiring diagram from inside the unit, ref. C12]

Comment: Look up a wiring diagram (or other documentation) to find the original values.

Comment: I checked the wiring diagram inside the unit. All it has is a label "C-12 CAPACITOR - DUAL". Checking several parts sources online, I found a number of different caps referenced for this model, ranging 300 to 500 volts,  5/30 uf to 7.5/60 uf.

Comment: @Tyson, I extended my online search but only found the same diagram, an installation guide, and a 2 page marketing flyer, nothing with specs on the cap or compressor.  Do you have access to more helpful info?  The original cap lasted 7 years, this one lasted 4. How long would you expect a cap to last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the Lennox web site to find a "store" near me and found an actual Lennox service center. They confirmed the 5/45 uf 440v dual run capacitor was correct. They didn't have any specs on the compressor coil resistance.

The service center didn't have any caps in stock but I found one at a local electrical supply house for under $10. It can also be ordered from Home Depot online (not available in stores) for about the same price.

I checked the resistance from each compressor terminal to ground (29-30 meg ohm each), re-checked the coil resistances (no change), put in the new cap, and turned it on.  I noticed the current draw is lower than expected (9.2A @ startup, 8.9A running @ 230V supply vs. 15.4A nameplate) but It's working fine so far.